# How to show if the sequence an=sin(n^2)/(n+1) is bounded?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$\ a_n$= $\frac {sin(n^2)}{n+1}$

How to show if the sequence above is bounded by 1/2 and -1/2? 
What I tried:

$\frac {sin(n^2)}{n+1}$ < $\frac {sin(n^2)}{n}$ < $\sin(n^2)$ <= 1

and I concluded that it should be bounded by -1 and 1 but that is not the right answer because the graph shows that it is bounded by 1/2 and -1/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that

$$-1 \le \sin \left( {{n^2}} \right) \le 1$$

then deviding by $n+1$ results in

$${{ - 1} \over {n + 1}} \le {{\sin \left( {{n^2}} \right)} \over {n + 1}} \le {1 \over {n + 1}}$$

but if

$$n = 1,2,3,...$$

You can conclude that

$$ - {1 \over 2} \le {{ - 1} \over {n + 1}} \le {{\sin \left( {{n^2}} \right)} \over {n + 1}} \le {1 \over {n + 1}} \le {1 \over 2}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot.

Comment: You are welcomed. Please check-mark my answer! Note the check-mark next to the answer. :)

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know I have to do that! (Im new to the website) thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

$|a_n| \leq \dfrac{1}{n+1} \leq \dfrac{1}{2}$ since $n \geq 1$.